# Micro 4/3 adapter for T-mount astronomy camera?

Tags: astrophotography, lens-mount, lens-adapter

Does there exist an adapter to mount Micro 4/3 lenses on a T-mount camera (43mm x 0.75mm thread)?

I want to attach the Mitakon Zhongyi Speedmaster 17mm f/0.95 Micro 4/3 lens to an Atik astronomical camera (cooled CCD, Atik 414ex mono).

Alternatively, an adapter that attached M43 lenses to a C-mount camera would work also. (Adapters that attach a C-mount lens on a M43 camera are easy to find - I need the opposite.)

Either adapter would have to place the M43 lens at the proper flange focal distance (19.25mm) from the sensor for infinity focus.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any adapter to attach MFT lenses to other mounts.  Even if they exist, you would lose infinity focus in most cases. (The FFD of MFT is 19.25mm. The FFD of T mount is 55mm.)

The FFD of C mount is 17.526. An adapter for MFT lenses would have to be 1.724mm thick.  That is not enough space to contain the parts of the MFT bayonet that recede into the camera body.